# Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier error?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to present a programmatically made viewcontroller on a viewcontroller, where I can't figure out how to make ID of such made-up viewcontroller.

As can be seen in the code under, I have a base view controller, 'ViewController' and if I click a button(didTapButton) I want a programmatically made view controller(SecondViewController) show up.
Though I can't set the second view controller's name, that I can't even execute the code -- instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController").

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondController")
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

......

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    private var customTransitioningDelegate = TransitioningDelegate()

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: "SecondController", bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}
```

How can I set up the second view controller's ID? If it's not what should be done, what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any identifiers for programmatically created vcs just do

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}
```

---

Use like

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = SecondViewController()
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            let vc2 = SecondViewController()
            vc2.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
            vc2.definesPresentationContext = true
            vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(vc2, animated: true)
        }
    }
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v = UIView()

        v.backgroundColor = .red

        view.addSubview(v)

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200),
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:200)

       ])

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. Though, I read an article which uses intantiateViewController to make viewcontroller show up with its size customized, so I was trying to use it. Is it still able to customize the size of the new view controller using your way?

Comment: Thanks! Much intuitive way it is.

Answer (score 1):

`instantiateViewController` lets you instanciate something that is defined in a given storyboard. So either you name it in the storyboard via xcode or you must do something else. For example, instanciate the object from code, ie `let c=SecondViewController()` (with appropriate parameters). You are trying to mix different ways to instanciate an object.